# Message bubble copy paste like whats app for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios7, message

I have SMS Reply screen in my project which is same as whats app. Screen contain message bubbles and "text view" for typing message which user want to send and send button. I am trying to write code for making copy/paste message bubble same as whats app. I have seen one demo code on net named "copyable cell", which use long press gesture for copy the content of table view cell. When I am trying to copy the message bubble, that cell becomes first responder and "text view" resign responder, due to that keyboard is hidden. So I cant copy message bubble when keyboard is visible. I have also tried with other temporary text field, but it is not working. I want solution that work for iOS5,6 and 7. Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: Look up UIPasteBoard. I've never used it myself, but I know that that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I have tried but issue is keyboard is resigning every time when I make copy. Any solution for that?

Comment: Your `UITextView` subclass should override `canResignFirstResponder` to return `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface TestViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextView *textView;

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)copyAction {
   /* Copies the string from the textView into the UIPasteBoard */

    UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    pasteBoard.persistent = YES;
    [appPasteBoard setString:self.textView.text];

}

- (NSString *)stringInPasteBoard {
    /* Returns the string in the UIPasteBoard if any */

    UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

    if([pasteBoard string] != NULL && [pasteBoard string].length > 0)
      return [pasteBoard string];


     return nil;

}

@end
```

Comment: Not this way. I want copy/paste like whats app. I want keyboard to remain active when I copy SMS bubble.

Comment: control this by not allowing the firstResponder to close the keyboard